# How to concatenate all results from table row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, row, string-concatenation

Can not find a solution to do something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', (
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1
))
```

How can I do that in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
SELECT t::text FROM tbl t WHERE id = 1;
```

- `t` is an alias for the table and not strictly needed. You can use the original table name as well. But if you have a column of the same name it takes precedence.
- So `t` represents the row type of the table, which is automatically coerced to text representation on output.
  I added an explicit cast to *make* it `text` internally as well - in case you want to do anything with it ...
  `t::text` is Postgres short notation for the SQL standard `cast (t AS text)`, which you can use as well. [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)
- You may want to trim the (single!) leading and trailing parentheses that denote a row type:

  ```
  SELECT right(left(t::text, -1), -1))
  FROM   tbl AS t
  WHERE  id = 1;
  ```
- "dirty", becaue you get Postgres row notation, the separator happens to be just the comma you asked for, but some values are also escaped and / or double quoted if needed.

Comment: how this operation "t::text" named ? documentation link ? ) thanks