# Where is the postgres sql 'cast a tuple' idiom documented?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I found an expression in a [postgres.org](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAEZATCUq--%2BzYAQxYfyO%2B3oPjCY6DWS5scET8PPHA7mhn7WDxg%40mail.gmail.com#CAEZATCUq--+zYAQxYfyO+3oPjCY6DWS5scET8PPHA7mhn7WDxg@mail.gmail.com) email, which seems useful, but whose documentation I've not been able to find.

```
select t.*::text from t
```

Here, the `::text` cast seems to apply to the each of the columns, and the resulting output as displayed by psql is a bit odd.   Perhaps someone could educate guys like me and unravel that mystery.

Edit: Curiously, the section [4.2.9. Type Casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) makes no reference to this syntax

Edit: Finally!  Related documentation found at [4.2.13. Row Constructors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can describe what's happening.  Consider this syntax:

```
select (1, 2)
```

This returns a record (or tuple) with two columns.  You can convert the tuple to text using either `cast()` or `::`:

```
select (1, 2)::text
```

The same thing occurs with the `t.*`.  It is interpreted as:

```
select (t.*)::text
```

You'll get the same result with:

```
select cast(t.* as text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your very clear response.  Interesting to find out that sql allows 'tuple' expressions: " ( a,b.c ) ".  Postgres actually has great documentation on this topic, at:
      8.16.5. Using Composite Types in Queries

Answer (score 2):

Just use the name (or alias) of the table `t` directly:

```
SELECT t::text FROM t
```

`t.*` would be used to decompose the row, but since you cast the whole row to text, the step is redundant noise.

The [cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) is possible because everything can be cast to `text` in Postgres. (There has to be a text representation for input / output.)

You get a text representation of the row either way. I.e. the output is the valid string literal, which you can cast back to the registered row type, like:

```
SELECT '(123,"some text",,"2017-01-03 02:27:27.930164+01")'::t
```

`t` being the name of a table or (materialized) view (visible in the current `search_path` or you have to schema-qualify) or any other registered (row) type.

This works with table names out of the box because Postgres registers a row type for every table you create.

Note, neither the `t.*` notation nor the cast back is possible for anonymous records (like `ROW(1,2)` or just `(1,2)` for short). There is no information about their structure in the system catalogs.

Related:

- [How to concatenate all results from table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918283/how-to-concatenate-all-results-from-table-row/23918319#23918319)